# Laravel check if user email verified

Tags: laravel

Hi i want to check if user email verified only in one function in a controller, i don't want to set the check in the middle-ware or in the route like this:

```
 public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('verified');
}
```

because the controller is accessible to guest also just one function (create) in the controller require email to be verified and user logged in how do i do that, thanks

```
        public function create()
    {

       // checking if authenticated but need to check if email verified also        
        if (Auth::check()) {

            // Get the currently authenticated user...
            $user = Auth::user();

            // get the list of states
            $states = State::orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
            // get all cities by state_id
            $state_id  = '1';

            $cities = City::where('state_id', $state_id)->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();

            return view('pages.create_product', ['user' => $user, 'states' => $states, 'cities' =>                     $cities]);
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would recommend you either do it in the `web.php` routes file like this:

```php
Route::get('example/create', ExampleController@create)->middleware('verified');
```

Or do it in the controller constructor but for a specific method like this:

```php
 public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('verified')->only('create');
}
```

If you really want to do it within the controller method, you can check by using this code.

```php
$user = Auth::user();

$user->hasVerifiedEmail();
```

And do not forget to include `MustVerifyEmail` interface on your `User` model.

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: thank you i dont want the first 2 solutions because those will lock the whole controller, i want to use third option but it gives me Undefined variable '$user' how do i define the $user

Comment: @Zeoneline no, the first 2 will not lock the whole controller, they are for specific method and route.

Comment: thank you Mr Andy, my bad i didnt pay attention to the details( ->only('create'); ) you are right, but perfect detailed answer all 3 answers works great, thank you so much i learned new things from you :)

Comment: one more question i have a // Resources routes how do i applay your first solution on Resources routes web.php to the create method on ProductController
Route::resources([
    'product' => 'ProductController',
    'user' => 'UserController',
    'profile' => 'UserController',
]);

Comment: @Zeoneline I think you can still pass the option as the second argument `Route::resources([ 'product' => 'ProductController', 'user' => 'UserController', 'profile' => 'UserController', ], ['only' => ['UserController.create']])->middleware('verified');`