# Laravel 9 : Date data null or not

Tags: laravel, phpmyadmin, laravel-9

I'm here to ask you a question for my Laravel 9 project if it's possible please :) !

I made an authentication with a user table. There is a column where you can check if the user verified his/her email or not. If he/she does, there is a datetime. If not, the column is null.

I would like to make a div in the profile section where there is an information for the user about the verification. If the verification is done, green information with the message "Good your email is verified", if not there is a red information with "Email not verified".

I tried this but it doesn't work, it stays on "NOT VERIFIED" however there is a datetime in this session user.

Do you know why ? Or how can I fix it ?
Thanks a lot !

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmlgQ.png)
[Data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gK1iU.png)

Comment: Could you include samples of your code?

Comment: Hi ! I put two images of my code at the end of my post :)
It's called "Code" and "Data structure", you click there and here it is ;)

Comment: Can you include full User Model, it seems like you might be using a custom way of logging in users as the suggested answers from users are not usable hmm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @if(Auth()->user()->isVerified)
       <div style="color:green">Good email is verified</div>
     @else
        <div style="color:red">Email not verified</div>
     @endif
```

Comment: I have this error when I try this : "Attempt to read property "isVerified" on null"

Comment: "Attempt to read property "isVerified" on null" will show if user is not logged in or unauthenticated for that. warp the above answer inside another  like  Auth::check()   or you can use short hand  Auth()->user()?->isVerified

Answer (score 0):

Please try using this

```
{{ auth()->user()->isVerified == null ? 'Not Verified' : 'Verified' }}
```

Comment: I have this error when I try this : "Attempt to read property "isVerified" on null"

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
@if(Auth::check())
  @if(Auth()->user()->isVerified)
    <div style='color:green'>Good your email is verified</div>
  @else
    <div style='color:red'>Email not verified</div>
  @endif
@endif
```

In Laravel there is a default method to determine if an email is verified or not. `isVerified` field is not necessary to check it.

checkout this answer [Laravel check if user email verified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63570181/19432371)